# Two-column RevTex blank space issues

Tags: graphics, two-column, revtex

I am a first time user of LaTeX and I am attempting to write a report featuring many graphs.

I am using the adapted from the American Physical Societies REVTeK-4 Pages format with the following preambles:

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,secnumarabic,nobalancelastpage,amsmath,amssymb,
    nofootinbib]{revtex4}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphics}      % standard graphics specifications
\usepackage{graphicx}      % alternative graphics specifications
\usepackage{longtable}     % helps with long table options
\usepackage{url}           % for on-line citations
\usepackage{bm}            % special 'bold-math' package
\usepackage{braket}          %bra-ket notation
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}         %font colour
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Upon placing 3 graphs using the following

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{ma.eps}
\caption{Average magnetisation per spin site versus temperature (black), Onsager's analytical prediction for the spontaneous magnetisation (red), Onsager's prediction for the critical temperature in an isotropic square lattice with $h=0$ (cyan).}\label{mag}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Section of complete blank space seem to appear in the columns, with no way to setting some text or graph in them. I have trying adjusting the size of the graphs, with no good results.

I shall add a part of my code, to provide a more concrete example:

```
\section{Results and analysis}

Some text.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{ma.eps}
\caption{Average magnetisation per spin site versus temperature (black), Onsager's analytical prediction for the spontaneous magnetisation (red), Onsager's prediction for the critical temperature in an isotropic square lattice with $h=0$ (cyan).}\label{mag}

\end{figure}

Some more text.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{ma.eps}
\caption{Average magnetisation per spin site versus temperature (black), Onsager's analytical prediction for the spontaneous magnetisation (red), Onsager's prediction for the critical temperature in an isotropic square lattice with $h=0$ (cyan).}\label{mag}
\end{figure}
```

Below I attach a screenshot of the compiled document.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Some more code that tries to reproduce the issue is needed for making a diagnosis.

Comment: Please provide minimal working example (MWE) which will will exhibit your problem. Not related, however, instead `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` rather use `\centering` after `\begin{figure}`

Comment: @Zarko, can I ask why?

Comment: Regarding `\centering`? `\begin{center} ...\end{center}` add to vertical spaces before and after picture provided by `float` additional space. At use of the `\centering˙this is not a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more extended comment ... I cant reproduce your problem. In test I first remove all twice loaded package, than move `hyperref` on the end of preamble, and package `lipsum` for dummy text. I got the following result:

[image]

Code used in test:

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,secnumarabic,nobalancelastpage,amsmath,amssymb,
    nofootinbib]{revtex4}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{graphics}      % <-- why? graphicx is sufficient specifications
%\usepackage{graphicx}      % <-- loaded second time
\usepackage{longtable}     % helps with long table options
%\usepackage{url}           % at package hyperref is surplus
\usepackage{bm}            % special 'bold-math' package
\usepackage{braket}          %bra-ket notation
%\usepackage{color} <-- at xcolor is surplus 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}         %font colour
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Average magnetisation per spin site versus temperature (black), Onsager's analytical prediction for the spontaneous magnetisation (red), Onsager's prediction for the critical temperature in an isotropic square lattice with $h=0$ (cyan).}
\label{mag}
\end{figure}

   \lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Average magnetisation per spin site versus temperature (black), Onsager's analytical prediction for the spontaneous magnetisation (red), Onsager's prediction for the critical temperature in an isotropic square lattice with $h=0$ (cyan).}
\label{mag}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Average magnetisation per spin site versus temperature (black), Onsager's analytical prediction for the spontaneous magnetisation (red), Onsager's prediction for the critical temperature in an isotropic square lattice with $h=0$ (cyan).}
\label{mag}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[4]
    \end{document}
```